Kasa HS200 Double Gang



Currently 2 single-pole light switches (S1 and S2) on the same box.They control the kitchen lights, and dining room lights+fan.
4 cables (2-wires) in the box.
One from Pannel, one for the next switch down the run, one for kitchen lights and one for dining room lights/fan.
All neutrals are connected to the wire nut.
All grounds are connected to a wire nut, and piggytail goes to S1 ground screw.
Line from panel+line for next run + piggytail connected to wire nut.
Piggytail is backstabbed on S1.
Load to lights is also backstabbed on S1.
Then there is a hot wire jumper from screw on S1 to S2.
Ground screw from S1 is also jumpered to ground screw on S2.
Load to lights is backstabbed on S2.
Each KASA HS200 switch has 4 wires (2 black, 1 white, 1 green).
My doubts come from that hot black cable jumper between S1 and S2.
What do i do? Is it ok to connect all the lines to a 5 port WAGO, and throw the jumper?
Clearly this jumper is feeding S2 from S1.
Lastly,
The current 4 neutrals would need to be connectes to the new neutral coming from each HS200, for a total of 6.
My WAGO has only 5 ports...can I use a 3 port to connect the 2 neutrals from the HS200s, and then connect a short cable from the 3rd port to a 5-port that has the current 4 neutrals?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FZm7gigoAgMZIhV_z7JUJGu7ovvJbDWb/view?usp=drivesdk

Photo of box wiring would help.

Its there hyperlink at the top

You can (and should) edit the picture(s) into your question, using the "mountains" icon at the top of the edit bar. Easier for your readers (help us help you) and more useful for future reference (not at risk of evaporating until Stack Exchange itself does).

@keshlam done! Dont know how I missed that

Yes it'll be fine (much better, IMHO) to feed S2 with a pigtail directly from the wirenut/WAGO rather than with a jumper from the screw of S1.
Yes, when the number of conductors to be joined is greater than the capacity of the available connector, it's necessary to daisy-chain multiple connectors. Your suggestion of a 5-port WAGO for the in-wall neutrals with an additional 3-port daisy-chained for connecting the switch neutrals is a fine way to do it.

Thanks Greg! I will give this a try and report back

done!like an idiot, i inverted the loads so now the left switch turns on the right lights :) pic added to the post
